# Laravel Eloquent relation not retrieving data from related table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Iv got a simple "publications" table and "Languages" table as seen below. All I want to do is output "available languages" associated with the publication. iv tried relationships this way and that and cnt get it right

[Publications Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4cRT.png)

[Languages Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dpMP.png)

Controller:

```
public function index()
{

    $publications = Publication::all();

    $languages = Language::all();

    return view('admin/publications/index', compact('publications', 'languages'));

}
```

Publication Model relationship:

```
public function languages(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Language');

}
```

[Publications Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZy1i.png)

Please help!

Comment: Your relations doesn't look right, both table have reference to each other ? Can you tell what is the exact relation between your tables is it one to many ? many to many  ?

Comment: Well, thats part of the problem, Im not sure which relation to use. A 'Publication' is available in many languages, so im using one to many ie publication 'hasMany' Languages

Comment: This sounds more like a many-to-many relationship: A publication is available in many languages. For a specific language many publications are available.

Comment: Did you define the inverse of the relationship using belongsTo?

Comment: I defined the relationship nw as 'publication hasMany languages' and inverse 'language belongsTo publication'. At best I get a response of "1", which is the value of the languages field in the publications table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `with` to include relations:

```
public function index()
{
    $publications = Publication::with('languages')->get();

    return view('admin/publications/index', compact('publications'));
}
```

This allows you to then access the related models like:

```
foreach ($publication->languages as $language) {
    echo $language->myAttribute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it worked, however I needed to add "publication_id" column to the Languages table aswell

Answer (score 0):

To access a relationship you use `with` like

```
//In your publications model add
function languages(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Languages','languages')//where languages is the foreing key.
}
```

Then in your controller you just do

```
$publications = Publication::with('languages')->get();
```

that way `$publications` will have all related languages in the `languages` property

Comment: I tried your suggestion and updated to the following "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'languages.languages' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `languages` where `languages`.`languages` in (1))"

Comment: you're trying to access languages in languages, as i wrote in the answer, that should be in your "publication" model

Comment: @CarlosSalazar the foreign key part should be publication_id i guess